# Insert query values from select query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert

i want to set the value to a `insert query` from `select query` ,how to perform this.

```
insert into t_user (id,user_id) values (1, ) 
where user_id in (select id from user where id=123)
```

I want to set the value of `user_id` from select query value ,how to do this in sql?

Comment: You already know the id you're inserting. why bother looking it up?

Comment: I DONT KNOW THE VALUE OF USER_ID ,I NEED THIS VALUE FROM SOME OTHER TABLE AND INSERT INTO T_USER

Comment: @Geoist I'm guessing because if id 123 doesn't exist in the database then it doesn't want to be inserted...

Comment: @harqs Could you be more specific as to where the values come from?

Comment: @harqs Then you need to better explain your question in terms of what you want, not how you think you want to get it.  Giving us a 1/2 baked sql query and saying ' how do i do this ' just leaves us having to infer what you want.  Maybe show us what your data structure looks like and we can probably help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO t_user (id, user_id)
SELECT 1, id 
FROM user
WHERE id = 123
```

Comment: what does select 1,id specifies?

Comment: @harqs, In your original query, you wrote `values(1, )`, so I assumed that you want to insert id = 1 for all the result set that would come from the select statement, but you can alter it to any selected value from the result set instead of 1.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal have problem in your select. Only select one id 123. It is strange and insert many, if have, (id=1, user_id=123). Question is no cleary

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into t_user(id, user_id) select 1, id from user where id=123;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into t_user (id,user_id)
select 1,id from user where id=123
```

if your table has only two columns then no need to specify columns again

```
  insert into t_user
  select 1,id from user where id=123
```

Answer (score 1):

And in that case, what's the problem with this:

```
INSERT INTO t_user(id, user_id) VALUES(1,123);
```

I mean the problem is a little bit strange, if you know both values from the start, why bother with select at all.

Comment: I DONT KNOW THE VALUE OF USER_ID ,I NEED THIS VALUE FROM SOME OTHER TABLE AND INSERT INTO T_USER

Comment: Actually - for this query - you do. You retrieve id from user where id = 123, that means you always retrieve id = 123, therefore those two queries are equivalent, unless user table does not contain such record at all

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO t_user(id, user_id)
       SELECT id,1
       FROM user ;
       WHERE id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table structure like this

```
----------      -------
 articles        users
----------      -------
 rowid           rowid
 article_id      user_id
 user_id         user_name
```

And a few entries like this

```
---------------------------------
 users
---------------------------------
 rowid     user_id     user_name
---------------------------------
   1         124         joe
   7         12309       mark
```

The correct way to insert a value based on a lookup / reference from another table would be this:

```
 INSERT INTO articles (rowid, article_id, user_id)
     SELECT 1, 12392, user_id FROM users
     WHERE rowid = 7
```

This would insert the following record into articles

```
---------------------------------
 articles
---------------------------------
 rowid     article_id    user_id 
---------------------------------
   1          12392       12309
```

It is beyond me, however, why you would use either this database design or insert method.

Comment: It is beyond me, however, why you would use either this database design or insert method. I did not get this point pls larify

Comment: Explaining why my example is not the definition of good practice is well outside the scope of SO.